# React Native Expo custom componant not diplaying

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I am a noob and cannot figure out why one of my custom componants is being displayed yet the other is not.

Home Sreen:

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, Text} from 'react-native';
import { SafeAreaView } from 'react-native-safe-area-context';
import { ScrollView, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import { DrawerActions } from '@react-navigation/native';
import Ionicons from '@expo/vector-icons/Ionicons';

import { useGrid } from '../context/gridProvider'; // context provider

import Exam from '../components/Exam';
import Clock from '../components/clock';

const Home = ({navigation}) => {

    const {checkedItems, setCheckedItmes} = useGrid()
    
    return (
      <SafeAreaView style={{flex:1}}>
        <ScrollView style={{padding:20}}>
          <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between', marginBottom:20,}}>
          <Text style={{fontSize: 16, fontWeight: 700}}></Text>
            <Text style={{fontSize: 32, fontWeight: 700, color:'#444'}}>Todays Exams</Text>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.openDrawer())}>
              <Ionicons name="menu" size={32} color="#333" />
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
          <Clock /> // the clock is displayed
          <Exam /> // the exam list is not displayed
        </ScrollView>
      </SafeAreaView>
    )
  }

  export default Home
```

The Clock displays yet the Exam does not.

Exam Component:

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, Text, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import { useGrid } from '../context/gridProvider';
import examData from '../data/trialData';

const Exam = () => {
  
  const {checkedItems, setCheckedItmes} = useGrid();

    checkedItems.forEach((key) => {

        console.log(examData[key-1].title);
        
        return(

          <View style={{flex:1, alignItems: 'center', marginTop: 100, flexDirection: 'row'}}>
              <Text style={{color: '#333'}}>{examData[key-1].title}</Text>
              <Text>{examData[key-1].startTime}</Text>
              <Text>{examData[key-1].endTime}</Text> 
          </View>  

        )
    });
}

export default Exam
```

(Note: my first object id is 1 not zero hence the -1 on the key value)

I have used context to handle the global availability of what exams have been selected from a list on another screen.

When you select exams from the list the `console.log(examData[key-1].title);` statement does output the correct information to the terminal however noting other than the clock is displayed in the APP

I have tried removing the clock component, just in case it was pushing the list off the page.

has anyone got any idea of what I've done wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function Exam always return undefined, due to [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach?retiredLocale=de#return_value) return undefined.

Solution: Use map instead of forEach.

```js
import React from 'react';
import {View, Text, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import { useGrid } from '../context/gridProvider';
import examData from '../data/trialData';

const Exam = () => {
  
  const {checkedItems, setCheckedItmes} = useGrid();

    checkedItems.forEach((key) => {

        console.log(examData[key-1].title);
        
        return(

          <View style={{flex:1, alignItems: 'center', marginTop: 100, flexDirection: 'row'}}>
              <Text style={{color: '#333'}}>{examData[key-1].title}</Text>
              <Text>{examData[key-1].startTime}</Text>
              <Text>{examData[key-1].endTime}</Text> 
          </View>  

        )
    });
}

export default Exam
```